# How to transform a dataframe to merge two columns' information for one-hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

Suppose I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with two categorical columns say, `Card` with two possible values "Visa" and "Master" and `Success` which takes values either `0` or `1`. Example:

| Index | Card | Success |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Visa | 0 |
| _ | Master | 1 |
| 2 | Visa | 1 |
| _ | Master | 0 |
| 3 | Visa | 1 |
| 4 | Master | 1 |

I want to transform it into a dataframe such that Card and Success attributes are joined and the following dataframe is produced:

| Index | Card_Visa_Success | Card_Master_Success |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 1 |

(default value of success is 0 if the corresponding row does not exist)

One way I could think of doing this is by using one hot encoding for Card attribute alone and then taking an AND (`df['Card_Visa_Success'] = df['Card_Visa'] & df['Success']`) with success column which would keep 1 only if both attributes are same. I want to ask if there is a simpler way of combining two columns of dataframes using some `pandas` or `sklearn` function? In addition to that, could you also help me writing a custom transformer for this operation so that I can integrate it in my `sklearn` pipeline? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a multi-indexed `pd.DataFrame` as shown in the input data I think you can get the result by using [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to pull one index level from the row -index into a column-index.

As the `unstack` operation gives us a [multi-index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html) for the columns, we need to merge the multi-index into a regular ones using a [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) operation.

I assume if there is no content in the `DataFrame` for a specific card-index combination it is not considered "successful", so we fill the missing values with `0`s.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Index': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4],
    'Card': ['Visa', 'Master', 'Visa', 'Master', 'Visa', 'Master'],
    'Success': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data).set_index(['Index','Card']).unstack().fillna(0.0)
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format) 
print(df)
```

```
       Success_Master  Success_Visa
Index                              
1                 1.0           0.0
2                 0.0           1.0
3                 0.0           1.0
4                 1.0           0.0
```

To fit this in an `sklearn` pipeline, you just need to implement a `transform` method on a `Transformer`:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class CardSuccessTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        X_transformed = X.copy()
        X_transformed = X_transformed.set_index(['Index', 'Card']).unstack().fillna(0.0)
        X_transformed.columns = X_transformed.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
        return X_transformed
```

You can find more information about how to write custom transformers and use them in your pipeline [here](https://www.andrewvillazon.com/custom-scikit-learn-transformers/):

```
pipe = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("card_success_transformer", CardSuccessTransformer())
    ]
)
transformed_df = pipe.fit_transform(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering on transformer part too, @Sebastian. While reading further about transformers, I read that "transformers must never change the number of rows." Should this be the case here?

Answer (score 2):

In pure pandas, you can go with a [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with `max` as aggregation function:

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index='Index', columns='Card', values='Success',
                      aggfunc='max', fill_value=0)
         # below is optional
         .rename(columns=lambda x: f'Card_{x}_Success')
         .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output:

```
   Index  Card_Master_Success  Card_Visa_Success
0      1                    1                  0
1      2                    0                  1
2      3                    0                  1
3      4                    1                  0
```